# Recommended size of memory and hard disk for a VirtualBox VM for Solaris with Oracle

Tags: hard-drive, virtualbox, memory, solaris, oracle-10g

I have a laptop with Windows 7 64-bit operating system. I have installed VirtualBox 5.1.14 on it. Now I want to create a Solaris 10 VM where I would like to install Oracle 10g. What is the recommended size of Virtual RAM and Virtual Hard Disk for such a case?

As per this link Solaris 10 expect at least 1.5GB RAM and 6GB Hard Disk size. 
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/solaris/overview/oracle-solaris-system-requirements-455519.html

Not sure about Oracle

Thanks =)

Comment: Those numbers seem really low to run Oracle 10G on Solaris.  How much memory does your laptop have?  How much disk space?  Also, when installing Solaris 10, don't accept the default disk partitioning if your installing a UFS root drive, or you'll wind up with way too much space in `/export/home` and not enough anywhere else.

Comment: I have 8GB memory and 458GB Hard Disk of which now 250GB is free

Answer (score 0):

Always limit the RAM used in the virtual machine so that you have ample ram for the host machine and the virtual machine.  If your host machine has less than 3.0 GB of RAM, I would recommend limiting the virtual machine's RAM to not more than 50% of the host's RAM.  As to the hard disk, it really depends upon how much space you have on the host system, but if possible you should go with the defaults.